# Rather than face/facing/to face

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, verbs

I was watching a series “The Affair”, where a character said this, “You wanted to die rather than face yourself”.

This dialogue is making me question if what’s the difference between these three:

> A. You wanted to die rather than face yourself.
>
> B. You wanted to die rather than facing yourself.
>
> C. You wanted to die rather than to face yourself.

Comment: I would say, A is the concise form of C and all three mean the same. The B might put more emphasis on the process though. But to me, all three essentially mean the same thing.

Comment: Native US speaker and the first one sounds correct and the other two sound awkward, but I’m not sure if they are technically correct or not.

Comment: Please refrain from engaging in arguments with other people. If you find the answers unsatisfactory, please try and clarify your question. You can also comment under answers _politely_, and request clarification and further explanation from answerers. Bickering will likely result in suspensions.

Comment: Ok, I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As a native UK English speaker, I would say A seemed the most natural. The other two sound a bit "foreign" to me, but I can't really explain why and I'm too busy to start analysing it.

Comment: The difference is that the first one (A) is correct and the other two are not.

Answer (score -1):

//A. You wanted to die rather than face yourself.

B. You wanted to die rather than facing yourself.

C. You wanted to die rather than to face yourself.//

When we use 'rather than' both the verbs should be similar.  It should be like rather die than face; or rather dying than facing.

It shouldn't be that rather is followed by 'die' and than is followed by 'facing', instead of 'face'.  Hence, the first examples is correct.